# Return uppercase UUID in FastApi

Tags: python, request, fastapi, uuid

When using FastApi with a pydantic model at the reponse model, I found that the uuid are always returned lowercase by the http response. Is there any standard way to return them upper cased?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from uuid import UUID
app = FastAPI()

class Test(BaseModel):
    ID: UUID

@app.get("/test", response_model=Test)
async def test():
    id_ = uuid.uuid4()
    return Test(ID=id_)
```

When making the request the returned uuid will be in lowercased.

```
from requestr
a = requests.get("http://localhost:800/test").text # you ir
# a -> '{"ID":"fffc0b5b-8e8d-4d06-b910-2ae8d616166c"}' # it is lowercased
```

The only somewhat hacky way I found to return them uppercased is overwriting the uuid class `__str__` method or sub-classing uuid:

What I tried (and works):

```
# use in main.py when importing for first time
def newstr(self):
    hex = '%032x' % self.int
    return ('%s-%s-%s-%s-%s' % (hex[:8], hex[8:12], hex[12:16], hex[16:20], hex[20:])).upper()


uuid.UUID.__str__ = newstr
```

But I was wondering if there is a standard way of doing this without modifying the original class, maybe a post process in pydantic or a setting in FastApi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define custom `json_encoders`:

```py
class Test(BaseModel):
    ID: UUID

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            UUID: lambda val: str(val).upper()
        }
```